Sending SMS using AT-Commands on VB.NET
I'm trying to send SMS messaging through VB.NET using AT-Commands. This is my code below:
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Class Form1
    Dim SerialPort1 As New System.IO.Ports.SerialPort\
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If SerialPort1.IsOpen Then
            SerialPort1.Close()
        End If

        With SerialPort1
            .PortName = "COM4"
            .BaudRate = 9600
            .DataBits = 8
            .Parity = Parity.None
            .StopBits = StopBits.One
            .Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend
            .DtrEnable = True
            .RtsEnable = True
            .NewLine = vbCrLf
        End With


        Try
            SerialPort1.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(SerialPort1.PortName & " is not available!")
        End Try

        If SerialPort1.IsOpen Then
            With SerialPort1
                .Write("AT" & vbCrLf)
                .Write("AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf)
                .Write("AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & txtRecepient.Text & Chr(34) & vbCrLf) 'Error begins here
                .Write(txtMessage.Text & Chr(26))
            End With
        Else
            MsgBox(SerialPort1.PortName & " is not available!")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class


The error begins when AT+CMGS gets executed; the whole code hangs. When I try to use If-Statements for each AT-command, the error begins at the first command .Write("AT" & vbCrLf).
I debugged with PuTTY and the commands were working as expected; it results in OK messages and PuTTY actually sends SMS messages to my phone.
However, when I try to integrate AT-Commands to my VB.NET Code, it breaks down.

You have two fundamental flaws in your AT command handling that MUST be fixed before anything will work, see the first and last bullet points in this answer. Also follow links from this answer.

The very important info contained in @hlovdal 's answer (which I reccomend you to read) is that some commands (+CMGS is one of them) may be abortable, and that's what probably happens to you by sending text before \r\n> prompt. Another thing I suggest is to check txtMessage.Text length before sending it, as +CMGS delivers a single SMS. Longer texts result in an ERROR response.
